# How to improve the code of function that has a value output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey so I have two functions in my User controller that are annoying me. They take up 10 lines each, and just look horrible. I don't really know how to improve the code of the function, but I refuse to believe it can't be made to look nicer than what it does.

```
def campaigns_per_hour
  if plan_id == 1
    10
  elsif plan_id == 2
    17
  elsif plan_id == 3
    25
  else
    17
  end
end
```

The user can subscribe to three different plans, and depending on the plan they have access to different amount of plans. Anybody know how I can improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an Array here, but they don't support defaults. It's also an id, not a number, so using a hash is fine semantically too.

```
plans = {1 => 10, 2 => 17, 3 => 25}
plans.default = 17
plans[plan_id]
```

Comment: @sja oops. symbol notation only works with valid symbol identifiers, and a number isn't one, e.g. `:5` is an invalid symbol.